# Rails 6 - All code changes are not updating on the screen when page refreshes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I updated to MAC Catalina recently and I've noticed since then that when I am in development no changes to any code are updated on the page when I refresh until I restart foreman and rails server. It's the same site I've been working on for a while and never had this issue. It doesn't matter if it is HTML, CSS, models, controller etc. Nothing is updating when code changes.

Any ideas what could be going on?

Update: I fixed it. It must have been something with where catalina moved my files to after the update. Putting the site into a new folder fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must have been something with where catalina moved my files to after the update. Putting the site into a new folder fixed the issue.